# Using SVG (raphaeljs) for developing map-based application

Tags: flash, cross-browser, svg, raphael

I am evaluating [raphaeljs](http://raphaeljs.com/) (SVG/VML) for developing a similar component like Flicr Map or Google Map based on purely drawing rather than utilizing images. Unlike, flickr map or google map our map will more interraction with user and lot of drawing is involved.

Can anyone advice me if using SVG/VML has any issues rather than Flash? It will help me to rule out SVG, if any have bad experience with it.

Note: If any one knows a huge implementation of SVG running live, it will help me to avoid POC in SVG.

Thanks ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vadi
there is an issue with Safari (occasionally) but I believe this has been catered for in the soon to be released 1.3.3

Peruse my site where I have been studying it and carrying out some experiments...
http://www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/raphaelsource.html